# Need to use another class type in angular model class

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use Salary Type for `salaries` class variable. how can i do it  ? please help me

```
export class Employee {

  id: string = "";
  birth_date: string = "";
  emp_no: string = "";
  first_name: string = "";
  last_name: string = "";
  gender: string = "";
  hire_date: string = "";
  salaries: Salary = "";

  constructor() {
    this.salaries = new Salary;

  }


}
```

```
export class Salary {

  id: string = "";
  emp_no: string = "";
  salary: string = "";
  rom_date: string = "";
  to_date: string = "";


}
```

Comment: so what error do you get? can you please add the code of `Salary`.

Comment: updated. i didn't get any error. is this correct way to define ? could you please confirm it . Also i can see warning "cannot find Salary"

Comment: @AmrithSudarshan `import` salary Class in your `Employee ` class. Also, how can you assign string to it ? `salaries: Salary = "";`  This is wrong. Import the class and VS code will guide you further

Comment: ``this.salaries = new Salary()`` should solve the problem. If you're not going to create Salary Class then you can create an interface instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two errors: `salaries: Salary = null;` and `this.salaries = new Salary();`

in many cases you don't need a class but you can use a Type or an interface, i.e.

```
export interface Employee {
    id?: string;
    birth_date?: string;
    emp_no?: string;
    first_name?: string;
    last_name?: string;
    gender?: string;
    hire_date?: string;
    salaries?: Salary;
}

export interface Salary {
    id?: string;
    emp_no?: string;
    salary?: string;
    rom_date?: string;
    to_date?: string;
}
```